# The [desktop] tag is ambiguous

Tags: discussion, status-completed, retag-request

[desktop](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/desktop) (x119) has questions that deal with either:

- desktop (as opposed to portable) computers
- an operating system's desktop environment

The tag wiki primarily concentrates on the former meaning, while mentioning the latter as an alternative. The topics are sufficiently different that I think the current situation is not optimal. Will post my suggestion as an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the tag should be disambiguated, for instance to [desktop-computer](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/desktop-computer) and [desktop-environment](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/desktop-environment), with [desktop](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/desktop) as a synonym for whichever of those is more popular (looking at the first couple of pages of [the tag's FAQ](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/desktop?sort=faq&pagesize=15), it would seem to be the latter).

I'm willing to go through the questions and retag as necessary, if this solution is accepted.

Comment: You would only need to retag the questions that apply to the less common tag (let's hypothetically assume `desktop-environment`), then the creation of the synonym would retag the remaining `desktop-computer` questions automatically. Before you start retagging, wait a little for community consensus or feedback though.

Comment: @slhck Of course, I had no intention of proceeding with this before getting some feedback :)

Comment: No objections, downvotes or alternative suggestions for over 5 days, so I'm going to go ahead with this.

Comment: Sounds good to me. Ping me when done and we'll take care of the mass retagging.

Comment: @slhck Done. I retagged 167 questions as [desktop-computer] (which, as I suspected, was the less popular one), and removed the [desktop] tag from a few questions that had nothing to do with either meaning of the word.

Comment: Alright; now thinking of it, "desktop" now either means the actual desktop of a computer, or its desktop environment (in the sense of GNOME, KDE, etc.), so we might need to go through them one more time to differentiate that. What do you think?

Comment: @slhck Good point. So if we use [desktop-environment] for software like Gnome and KDE, what tag to use for questions about the actual desktop? [desktop-interface]? [graphical-desktop]? [desktop-metaphor] (per the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Desktop_metaphor))? None of them seem very intuitive. How about just leaving [desktop] for those questions (rather than making it a synonym), and have the tag wiki excerpt point to [desktop-computer] and [desktop-environment]?

Comment: I would probably just use "desktop", yeah :)

Comment: @slhck Alright, I'll go through them once more and retag as [desktop-environment] where necessary.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to do this! If you ask on chat, maybe someone wants to help out?

Comment: @slhck I've been going through the questions, and it seems like in most cases the [desktop-environment] tag would actually be redundant - all except a small handful of questions are about a specific desktop environment, each of which already have individual tags, and adding the generic tag seems unnecessary; after all, we don't tag Windows questions as [operating-system]. So I think for most questions about desktop environments I'll just remove the [desktop] tag, add the specific DE tag where it's missing, and add [desktop-environment] only to those that truly are broad or ambiguous enough.

Comment: Wanted to quickly get your opinion before doing any actual edits, though.

Comment: Yeah, that sounds like a good idea, especially the point about tags that are too broad. Absolutely fine with me!

Comment: @slhck I was away for a while, but it should be done finally. I also updated the tag wikis, so this can be marked as [status-completed].